# How to implement pagination in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React js and this might sound like a newbie question. I am trying to implement a paginate function in react js from an API data. I am not sure how to implement the logic though. I have passed on props like the page size, current page and the data that needs to be rendered. Here is my code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Result from './Result';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Card from './Card';
import Loading from './Loading'
import Paginate from './Paginate';


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      totalData:[],
      searchText:'',
      searchResult:[],
      isSearch:false,
      isLoading:true,
      pageSize:15,
      currentPage:1
    }
    this.onSearchChange=this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePageChange=this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSearchChange= (e) =>{
    console.log("search change "+this.state.searchText)
    this.setState({
      searchText:e.target.value,
      isSearch:true
    })
    console.log("api data"+this.state.data[0])
  }

  /* fetchSearchResult= () =>{
    console.log(this.state.searchText)
    console.log("inside fetch")
   let store= this.state.data.map(item=>{
      let {country}=item
      return(country)
    })
    console.log(store)
    var areEqual = store.includes(this.state.searchText);
     console.log(this.state.areEqual)
     return (areEqual)? 
      store:'not matched'
  //  return store;

  } */

  componentDidMount() {
    const url =
    'https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country'
    fetch(url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          data: result.reverse(),
          isLoading:false
        })
      })
      const totalUrl =
      'https://corona.lmao.ninja/all'
      fetch(totalUrl)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(result => {
          //let store=result;
          //console.log("store data"+store)
          this.setState({
            totalData: result
          })
          console.log("2nd fetched data"+this.state.totalData)
        })   
  }

  handlePageChange= (page) =>{
    this.setState({
      currentPage:page
    })

  }
  render() {
    return (

       this.state.isLoading?<Loading/>:
       <div id="main">
       <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
    <Button id="live_text"
    >Live</Button>
      <img
        alt=""
        src="/logo.svg"
        width="100"
        height="30"
        className="d-inline-block align-top"
      />{' '}
     Covid-19 dashboard
     {this.state.curTime}
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Navbar>

      <Form.Group>
       <Form.Label>Search</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control value={this.state.searchText}onChange={this.onSearchChange} type="text" placeholder="Enter country" />
      </Form.Group>
        <Card totalData={this.state.totalData}/>
      <Paginate 
        dataCount={this.state.data.length} 
        pageSize={this.state.pageSize}
        onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
        currentPage={this.state.currentPage}/>

        <Result data={this.state.data} 
        toSearch={this.state.searchText} 
        searchCheck={this.state.isSearch}
        searchValue={this.state.searchText}/>

    </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Paginate.js

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default function Paginate(props) {
    const {pageSize, dataCount, onPageChange, currentPage}=props;
    console.log("current page"+currentPage)
    const pagesCount=Math.ceil(dataCount/pageSize);
    const pages=_.range(1,pagesCount+1);
    return (
        <div>
            <nav aria-label="...">
  <ul class="pagination">
      {pages.map((page)=>{
          return(
        <li key={page}class={(page===currentPage)?"page-item active":"page-item"}>
        <a class="page-link" href="#" onClick={()=>onPageChange(page)}>{page}</a>
        </li>
          )
      })}


  </ul>
</nav>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Result.js

```
import React  from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const Result = (props) => {
    console.log('props value is:'+props.data)
    let {searchCheck, searchValue}=props;


   let update=props.data.map((item)=>{

    const { countryInfo, country, cases, deaths, recovered, active, casesPerOneMillion} = item;
    return(
    (searchCheck)?country.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase())?
        <tbody>
        <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
          <td><img style={{height:'25px',width:'50px'}}src={countryInfo.flag}/></td>
         <td>{country}</td>
          <td>{cases}</td>
          <td>{active}</td>
          <td>{recovered}</td>
          <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
          <td>{deaths}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>:
      '':
      <tbody>
        <tr key={countryInfo._id}>
          <td><img style={{height:'25px',width:'50px'}}src={countryInfo.flag}/></td>
         <td>{country}</td>
          <td>{cases}</td>
          <td>{active}</td>
          <td>{recovered}</td>
          <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
          <td>{deaths}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    )  
    })
    return (
      <div>
          <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
          <thead>
        <tr>

          <th>Flag</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Cases</th>
          <th>Active</th>
          <th>Recovered</th>
          <th>Cases per one Million</th>
          <th>Deaths</th>


        </tr>
      </thead>
          {update}
          </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
export default Result;
```

[Codesandbox live](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-yalow-4xpdn)

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, I am fetching the required records from data based on page no and storing them in a new array( as a state) and passing them to Result.js

Tips: Use the key in Result.js at the top level of children in Result.js you are using the key at the  tag instead of that you need to you it on

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Result from "./Result";

import Paginate from "./Paginate";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      totalData: [],
      searchText: "",
      searchResult: [],
      isSearch: false,
      isLoading: true,
      pageSize: 15,
      currentPage: 1,
      dataToShow: []
    };
    this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSearchChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchText: e.target.value,
      isSearch: e.target.value === "" ? false : true
    });
  };

  /* fetchSearchResult= () =>{
    console.log(this.state.searchText)
    console.log("inside fetch")
   let store= this.state.data.map(item=>{
      let {country}=item
      return(country)
    })
    console.log(store)
    var areEqual = store.includes(this.state.searchText);
     console.log(this.state.areEqual)
     return (areEqual)? 
      store:'not matched'
  //  return store;

  } */

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?sort=country";
    fetch(url)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          data: result.reverse(),
          dataToShow: result.slice(0, 15),
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
    const totalUrl = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/all";
    fetch(totalUrl)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        // let store=result;
        // console.log("store data"+store)
        this.setState({
          totalData: result
        });
      });
  }

  handlePageChange = page => {
    const { data, pageSize } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      currentPage: page,
      dataToShow: data.slice(pageSize * (page - 1), pageSize * (page - 1) + 15)
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      searchText,
      data,
      pageSize,
      currentPage,
      isSearch,
      dataToShow
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <input
          value={searchText}
          onChange={this.onSearchChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter country"
        />

        <Paginate
          dataCount={data.length}
          pageSize={pageSize}
          onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
          currentPage={currentPage}
        />

        <Result
          data={isSearch ? data : dataToShow}
          toSearch={searchText}
          searchCheck={isSearch}
          searchValue={searchText}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Paginate.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Paginate(props) {
  const { pageSize, dataCount, onPageChange } = props;
  const pagesCount = Math.ceil(dataCount / pageSize);
  const Pages = new Array(pagesCount).fill(0);
  // const Pages = [1,2,3,5]
  return (
    <div>
      <nav aria-label="...">
        {Pages.map((element, index) => (
          <button
            key={index}
            type="button"
            onClick={() => onPageChange(index + 1)}
          >
            {index + 1}
          </button>
        ))}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Result.js

```
import React from "react";

const Result = props => {
  const { searchCheck, searchValue } = props;

  const update = props.data.map(item => {
    const {
      countryInfo,
      country,
      cases,
      deaths,
      recovered,
      active,
      casesPerOneMillion
    } = item;
    return searchCheck ? (
      country.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase()) ? (
        <tbody key={countryInfo._id}>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img
                style={{ height: "25px", width: "50px" }}
                src={countryInfo.flag}
              />
            </td>
            <td>{country}</td>
            <td>{cases}</td>
            <td>{active}</td>
            <td>{recovered}</td>
            <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
            <td>{deaths}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      ) : (
        ""
      )
    ) : (
      <tbody key={countryInfo._id}>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img
              style={{ height: "25px", width: "50px" }}
              src={countryInfo.flag}
            />
          </td>
          <td>{country}</td>
          <td>{cases}</td>
          <td>{active}</td>
          <td>{recovered}</td>
          <th>{casesPerOneMillion}</th>
          <td>{deaths}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Flag</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Cases</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th>Recovered</th>
            <th>Cases per one Million</th>
            <th>Deaths</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {update}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Result;
```